# Nextjs13. Server actions in "alpha"

Tags: client-server, next.js13

I have implemented server actions in my nextjs 13.4 app? The documentations says they an experimental feature. But I have used them...They seem to be working? Now, I want to deploy to production. What can be the implications of having enabled an experimental feature.
Here is how, I have enabled them...What can I expect in production when they get stable
`module.exports = { experimental: { serverActions: true, }, }`

I just want to know the implications of a alpha feature

Answer (score 0):

You can still use experimental features but it wasn't released fully. So there can be a bug, performance issue, build issue or maybe they remove this feature completely, etc. When a stable version is released you have to upgrade your next package to get new updates.

Comment: thanks for info...at the moment they are buggy